# Bounded holomorphic function on half-plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function and bounded of half-plane $\mathbb H=\{z=x+iy\in \mathbb C| y>0\}$. I consider the function  $G(z)=\int_0^1 f(tz)dt$. I think $G(z)$ must be holomorphic on $\mathbb H$, but I have no idea to prove it. Could you give me some hints.

Comment: Holomorphic functions have an integral representation - does that help you?

Comment: $G(z) = \int_0^1 f(tz)dt= \frac{1}{z} \int_0^1 f(tz)d(tz) =  \frac{1}{z} \int_0^z f(s)ds$.

Comment: @Paul What do you mean ??

Comment: @ JieFan What happens if $f$ was holomorphic on $\mathbb{H} \setminus \{z_0\}$ with a pole of order $1$ at $z_0 = 15 i + 2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to show that such integrals are holomorphic is to use the dominated convergence theorem to see that $G$ is a continuous function, and then use Morera's theorem to see it is holomorphic.

Since $(t,z) \mapsto f(tz)$ is continuous on $(0,1]\times \mathbb{H}$ and $f$ is bounded, the application of the dominated convergence theorem is straightforward here.